# Check string for all lowercase letters in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, case

I want to be able to test if a PowerShell string is all lowercase letters.

I am not the worlds best regex monkey, but I have been trying along these lines:

```
if ($mystring -match "[a-z]^[A-Z]") {
    echo "its lower!"
}
```

But of course they doesn't work, and searching the Internet hasn't got me anywhere. Is there a way to do this (besides testing every character in a loop)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PowerShell by default matches case-insensitively, so you need to use the `-cmatch` operator:

```
if ($mystring -cmatch "^[a-z]*$") { ... }
```

`-cmatch` is *always* case-sensitive, while `-imatch` is always case-insensitive.

Side note: Your regular expression was also a little weird. Basically you want the one I provided here which consists of

- The [*anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string (`^`)
- A [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of lower-case Latin letters (`[a-z]`)
- A [*quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), telling to repeat the character class at least 0 times, thereby matching as many characters as needed (`*`). You can use `+` instead to disallow an empty string.
- The [*anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the end of the string (`$`). The two anchors make sure that the regular expression has to match *every* character in the string. If you'd just use `[a-z]*` then this would match any string that has a string of at least `0` lower-case letters *somewhere* in it. Which would be every string.

P.S.: Ahmad has a point, though, that if your string might consist of other things than letters too and you want to make sure that every *letter* in it is lower-case, instead of also requiring that the string consists solely of letters, then you have to invert the character class, sort of:

```
if ($mystring -cmatch "^[^A-Z]*$") { ... }
```

The `^` at the start of the character class *inverts* the class, matching every character *not* included. Thereby this regular expression would only fail if the string contains upper-case letters somewhere. Still, the `-cmatch` is still needed.

Answer (score 11):

If your test is so simple, you can and probably should avoid the use of regular expressions:

```
$mystring -ceq $mystring.ToLower()
```

Comment: Make sure to use the method's overloaded signature accepting a `CultureInfo` object if you need too.

Comment: I tested both the accepted answer and this one on a txt file with 20,643 rows and this answer took roughly 1/2 the time to process in every run than the accepted answer.

Comment: I also wanted to say that this answer is why I will google simple problems even though I know one way to accomplish them. This is so "weird", I never would have considered this tactic for matching. It reminds me of when I was just learning to program and saw `myBoolVar = !myBoolVar` for the first time to toggle a Boolean.

Comment: I was using -eq and couldn't figure out for the life of me why it was always true.  -ceq did the trick!

Comment: This also has the advantage of working with non-English strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern, which matches anything that is *not* an uppercase letter: `"^[^A-Z]*$"`

This would return false for any uppercase letters while allowing the string to contain other items as long as all letters are lowercase. For example, "hello world 123" would be valid.

If you strictly want letters without spaces, numbers etc., then Johannes's solution fits.

Comment: PowerShell matches case-insensitively by default, thereby this can't work. Not without another operator.