# How to replace strings in PowerShell with case-insensitive matching while preserving the input case

Tags: powershell, replace, text-processing

I want to replace multiple strings from a file. If the string is in upper case then replace with an upper case letter. If it is in lower case then replace it in lower case letter.

So far my code looks like the following. It does replace, but it does not do case wise replace.

```
(Get-Content $xyx -ErrorAction Stop) | Foreach-Object {
  $_ -replace 'abc001', 'abc002' -replace 'cde001', 'cde002' 
} | Set-Content $xyz
```

Sometimes the string I am replacing is in upper case. So I need to introduce a check if it is upper case replace with upper case else lowercase.

How can write this code?

<sup>Editor's note: The requirement to match case-insensitively while preserving the original case in the replacement string wasn't quite obvious when this question was first posted - the title was amended later, after some of the answers were posted.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is **a replacement operation that is case-*insensitive* on *matching*, but case-*preserving* on *replacement*.**

You don't specify the exact relationship between strings to match and what to replace them with, but going by your sample command:

```
(Get-Content $xyx -ErrorAction Stop) -replace '(abc00)1', '${1}2' -replace 
                                              '(cde00)1', '${1}2' | Set-Content $xyz
```

<sup>Note: With the specific replacements at hand, combining them into a single operation is possible:

`... -replace '(abc00|cde00)1', '${1}2'`</sup>

- Given that `-regex` is case-insensitive by default, it will match all case variations of `abc` and `cde`, but capture them with their *original* case in the 1st (and only) capture group (`(...)`), which can referenced as `${1}` in the replacement operand (or just `$1`, if there's no ambiguity).
- Also note how I've omitted a `ForEach-Cmdlet` call, because you can apply `-replace` directly to the array of lines that `(Get-Content ...)` returns; with an array that is already in memory in full, this approach is not only shorter, but noticeably faster.

To provide a simple example:

```
PS> 'aBc001' -replace '(abc00)1', '${1}2'
aBc002    # input case was preserved
```

Comment: if I write this code in one line it works but if I break It in 3 lines it gives me syntax error. :)

Comment: @Ashis: You cannot break the line in arbitrary places; if in doubt, place a `\`` at the very end of a line to force line continuation (to make PowerShell consider the next line a continuation of the current one).

Answer (score 1):

The `-replace` regex operator is case *in*-sensitive by default. If you want to change that behavior you need to use regex modifiers (`-replace '(?-i)abc001', 'abc002'`) or more simply `-creplace 'abc001', 'abc002'` to make the operation case sensitive.

However, since you do not seem to be using regex here, I would instead suggest you use the string operator `.Replace()` as it is case sensitive by default.

```
$_.Replace('abc001', 'abc002').Replace('cde001', 'cde002')
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I get syntax error   Get-Content $xyz-ErrorAction Stop) | Foreach-Object {
     $_.replace (abc01, 'abc02' ) `
        .replace ( 'cde01', 'cde02')`
                    } | Set-Content $xyz   , could you please help me with syntax.

Comment: Your code in comments has spaces that my answer does not. As well as a closing brace with no opening.. missing quotes on strings.... I suggest you use an editor like PowerShell ISE. It can help highlight these issues in testing.

Answer (score 0):

From another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098485/check-string-for-all-lowercase-letters-in-powershell), try something like this -

```
$i = 0
(Get-Content $xyx -ErrorAction Stop) | Foreach-Object {
    $line = $_[$i];
    if ($line -cmatch "^[^a-z]*$")
    {
        $line -replace $Matches.Value, 'YourNewValue'.ToUpper()
    }
    elseif ($line -cmatch "^[^A-Z]*$")
    {
        $line -replace $Matches.Value, 'YourNewValue'.ToLower()
    }
    $i++    
} | Set-Content $xyz
```

The original answer uses regex matching. The explanation for the regex is already mentioned in the original answer. All I am doing is introducing a check for uppercase and lowercase and replacing it likewise.

Like mentioned in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098485/check-string-for-all-lowercase-letters-in-powershell), the trick is to use `-cmatch` operator. `-cmatch` is *always* case-sensitive.

Coming to the regex,

- The [*anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string (`^`)
- A [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of lower-case Latin letters (`[a-z]`). Likewise (`[A-z]` for upper case).
- A [*quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), telling to repeat the character class at least 0 times, thereby matching as many characters as needed (`*`). You can use `+` instead to disallow an empty string.
- The [*anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the end of the string (`$`). The two anchors make sure that the regular expression has to match *every* character in the string. If you'd just use `[a-z]*` then this would match any string that has a string of at least `0` lower-case letters *somewhere* in it. Which would be every string.

If your string might consist of other things than letters too and you want to make sure that every *letter* in it is lower-case, instead of also requiring that the string consists solely of letters, then you have to invert the character class, sort of:

```
if ($xyz -cmatch "^[^A-Z]*$") { ... }
```

The `^` at the start of the character class *inverts* the class, matching every character *not* included. Thereby this regular expression would only fail if the string contains upper-case letters somewhere. Still, the `-cmatch` is still needed.

Comment: Thank you Vivek for the code.  I did not understand how to check if the value is upper case or lower. in the above code how it will know if the value is upper or lower. I used your code like

Comment: $i = 0
(Get-Content $xyz -ErrorAction Stop) | Foreach-Object {
    $line = $_[$i];
    if ($line -cmatch "^[^a-z]*$")
    {
        $line -replace $Matches.value, 'abc001'.ToUpper()
    }
    elseif ($line -cmatch "^[^A-Z]*$")
    {
        $line -replace $Matches.value, 'abc001'.ToLower()
    }
    $i++    
} | Set-Content $xyz    I m sure I m doing something wrong, as an output I am getting all the  abc001 in all the lines.

Comment: That is because for each line of input you are always replacing the value to `'abc001`. You are always replacing the loop with `'abc001`.